# FluentValidation package configuration problem in dotnet CQRS&&Onion pattern project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, asp.net-core

I want to integrate FluentValidation in my project directly through the filter because it is a CQRS project. I created a validator in my application layer it is calling CreateBook ,and I needed to integrate it via a Filter, I wrote a filter validation filter in the infrastructure.

```
public class ValidationFilter:IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var errors = context.ModelState
                .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Any())
                .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage))
                .ToArray();

            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(errors);
            return;
        }

        await next();
    }
}
```

Since my CreateBook filter is in the application layer, I need to add serviceregistration as well, but I'm confused.

public static class ServiceRegistiration
{

```
public static void AddApplicationService(this IServiceCollection collection)
{
    collection.AddMediatR(typeof(ServiceRegistiration));
      collection.AddScoped<IValidator<VM_Create_Book>, CreateBookValidator>();
    collection.AddHttpClient();
    //collection.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation();
    //collection.AddFluentValidationClientsideAdapters();
    //collection.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(typeof(CreateBookValidator).Assembly);
    // collection.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<CreateBookValidator>();


}
```

}

program.cs is like this

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddPersistenceServices();
builder.Services.AddApplicationService();

builder.Services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation();
builder.Services.AddFluentValidationClientsideAdapters();
builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(typeof(CreateBookValidator).Assembly);
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add<ValidationFilter>();
});

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

`

```
`builder.Services.AddControllers(options =\>
{
options.Filters.Add\<ValidationFilter\>();
}).AddFluentValidation() `
```

`
AddFluentValidation is deprecated in this section This usage has been removed so.
In short, I'm lost in the project, can someone guide me?

I was trying to integrate FluentVALIDATION but I was lost

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).